# Sketchup API Draw a concave polygon in view class

Tags: ruby, sketchup

Does View class in Sketchup API have method for drawing concave polygon. I found no method for doing it. 
Method draw of View class: `view.draw GL_POLYGON`, `@arr_vertex` can only draw convex polygon.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't one. View.draw is basically straight-to-OpenGL drawing so it requires convex polygons. You'll need to tessellate the polygon into convex polygons yourself.